# Post an int from a PHP client to a asp.net webservice is always 0

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

Hi I seem have created a SOAP webservice using asp.net , and tested it using an PHP client to get data.And it seems for getting data the service works.

THe problem appears when I try to post the data.It seems that the server always recieve the value 0.Here is my asp.net web service code:

```
public void DeleteBook(int categoryId)
    {
        using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new OdbcCommand())
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@CategoryId", categoryId));
                command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Books WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my PHP Soap client code:

```
  $client = new SoapClient($url);
  if(isset($_POST["id"])){
            $id = $_POST["id"];
            echo $id;
            $client->DeleteBook($id);
   }
```

I debugged the service and it seems the DeleteBook method get's hit but the problem is that the categoryId is 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing a string, but the endpoint expects an integer. It's likely the string is converted to 0 then. But that's just a guess, not a true analysis.

Comment: Hay what categoryId show in DeleteBook function? Is that same with your Post request in php? If same, ExecuteNonQuyery return how many row effect in your database. I mean, if 1 record is effect, that will return 1. If 2 record is effect, that will return 2. If no row is effected, that will return 0. Make sense? That my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I managed to solve this problem by actualy sending the parameter as an array.This is what I have done and it worked:

```
if(isset($_POST["id"])){
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $obj = array("categoryId" => $id);
        $client->DeleteBook($obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the string to an integer. You can do this either on the client or server side.

Try writing `(int) $id` in your PHP code, does this do the trick?

```
 $client = new SoapClient($url);
  if(isset($_POST["id"])){
        $id = (int) $_POST["id"];
        echo $id;
        $client->DeleteBook($id);
  }
```

I think that anything that can't be parsed to a integer will be 0.

Comment: I have tryed it but it still get's sent as 0

Comment: Do a var dump on $_POST["id"] before sending it to the client. What does it show?

Comment: Then we know that you are sending an integer to the server from the client. Let's move on to the server side. If you try to debug your DeleteBook method, what is the value of `ìnt categoryId`?

Comment: when the call reaches the server the value of categoryId is 0